# Converting double to string in java for a netbeans gui

Tags: java, netbeans-8

i want the total text field (txtTotal) to display the running total of the cost of the food order. however i get an error as it says that the last line is incorrect because you cannot convert a double to string.
What should I do??

```
    txtOrder.setText("Soup of the Day");
    txtPrice.setText("€4.00");
    total=total+crapClaws;
    txtTotal.setText(total);
```

Comment: `txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));` or `txtTotal.setText("" + total);` or `txtTotal.setText(Double.toString(total));` Myself, however, I'd use a NumberFormat currency instance, `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` to help my format my number into a currency String if that is what I were wanting to display.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is correct, here is some explanation:
`cannot convert a double to string` is the key here. What is the datatype of `total` ? I suspect it is double. You them attempt to set the text box to total - this is a double and a text box will only display Strings. Cast or convert your double value to string as above and you will have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a double to a String in a number of ways. Any of the following will work:

```
txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
txtTotal.setText(Double.toString(total));
txtTotal.setText("" + total);
```

The first to solutions call a method which converts a double into a String explicitly; the last solution uses the fact that Java lets you concatenate an arbitrary value with a string with a string as result.

Having said the above, however, you should know that it is a very bad idea to use double to represent currency values. Doubles use binary floating point numbers, and this means that a lot of values cannot be exactly represented. For example, 0.1 has no exact representation as a double. If you calculate with the currency values a lot, this will almost certainly lead to unexpected results.

You should use `BigDecimal` to represent currency values, or store the number of cents in a `long` or `int`.

Comment: `0.1` [does have an exact representation as a double](https://ideone.com/bD6UxO). Choosing the right type to use for currency is tricky - I wouldn't advise him to mess with what he has, since he's just adding totals.

Comment: @mk. You're wrong, 0.1 does not have an exact representation as a double. Try multiplying it with `1000000000000000000L` and see what `println` outputs then. System.out.println(double) will not necessarily give you the exact value of a double, but only enough decimals to uniquely distinguish it from the other possible double values.

Comment: Multiplying it a primitive by N produces a brand new numeric value according to the type's multiplication rules. Floating point values have multiplication rules that look "inexact", but the values themselves are still exact. If you disagree, maybe this would make a good question for you to ask.

Comment: @mk. You're right that my example doesn't show that you're wrong. The long is far too high for that. But your code doesn't show anything either, because println is not required to give the exact value of a double. Read http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/ .

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

```
txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

the method `setText` is expecting a `String` value, but you are giving it a `double`. You need to convert that double. Some methods, like `System.out.println`, provide convenience overloads that do take many different types, so you may be used to having this "just work", but that isn't the case with `setText`.

...just an aside, you might want to doublecheck that the soup of the day is in fact `crapClaws`.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote as your answer is in essence correct.